# analog of `let` in ExUnit

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

As you know, `rspec` supports `let` in its tests. It's quite helpful and shorts code a lot by predefining common variables and share them between tests.

How can I invoke this functionality in `ExUnit`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the better way to have the same behavior on Elixir with ExUnit, is using `setup_all` or `setup`.

> The setup_all callbacks are invoked once to setup the test case before any test is run and all setup callbacks are run before each test. No callback runs if the test case has no tests or all tests were filtered out.

Complete documentation can be found here: https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html

Comment: Also, when you "compose" test cases the `setup` cases defined in the "ancestor" cases are also invoked. Have a look at how the default `ConnCase` is defined by phoenix to see what I mean. With this you can "sort of" achieve what we get in `rspec` by nesting `lets` and context blocks

Answer (score 7):

I think the closest analog is returning a context from a setup hook. Take a look at this example adapted from [the ExUnit.Callbacks documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html):

```
defmodule AssertionTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  setup do
    {:ok, hello: "world"}
  end

  test "a test", context do
    assert(context[:hello] == "world")
  end
end
```

Comment: It is also common to pattern match on context like this:
`test "a test", %{hello: hello} do ...` The `hello` variable will have `"world"` value.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good way to approach this is, *assuming the stuff you would bind with `let` is dynamic*, to have a private function in your test case that computes the value you need.

```
defmodule MyModuleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "timestamp is a tuple" do
    assert is_tuple(my_var())
  end

  defp my_var() do
    :os.timestamp()
  end
end
```

RSpec's `let` also gives you caching of the value it computes; you could do this through the use of the [process dictionary](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced#dict), but that's usually discouraged. In any case, having this cached is very easily achievable by just storing the result in a variable inside the test:

```
test "timestamp is a tuple" do
  my_var = my_var()
  assert is_tuple(my_var)
  # other stuff that uses my_var
end
```

It's slightly more verbose but **hugely** less "magic" and more explicit :).

Comment: Btw, yeah returning a context from `setup` is probably a more common thing to do as Paweł showed :)

Comment: +1. I usually only create private functions to abstract some boilerplate "actions", and prefer setup & context when creating test data.